legacy elastic beanstalk application failing to run ebextension with CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
We have an old legacy app that runs on elastic beanstalk. This week the app started failing to deploy, with the following error:
Failed to retrieve https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/releases/download/v0.18/remote_syslog_linux_amd64.tar.gz: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727).
This is the syslog app for papertrail that is installed on deploy, as per papertrail's instructions...
https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/blob/master/examples/remote_syslog.ebextensions.config
I am assuming its some crt issue regarding root CA (as its an old box that EB uses), but if I ssh into the box in question, I can download remote_syslog_linux_amd64 fine with CURL, and even via python which is what eb runs in (i think).
If I try to update the ca-certificates I get package ca-certificates-2018.2.22-65.1.22.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version
So a bit lost as to how to solve this...
